# java video socket streaming to webview player

Tags: java, video, media

I am stumped.

I need to stream a video using my own server to a player.

How to stream a video stream to the WebView player?

Server ====socket video stream=====> Client ====> WebView player

Comment: do you need to develop the server with java?

Comment: About which WebView implementation are you talking? There is very little context information in your question.

Comment: I already have a server. It will keep sending byte[], which the client will dump it all into a byte array stream, which is then supposed to be read by the player. I am aiming to do it for both Android's WebView in Android 5.0.2 (and later) and Java 8 (and later).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a simple solution that works you can use a static video file on your server and the HTML5 video tag in your webView.

On Android, at this time, you need to have hardware acceleration turned on to support HTML5 video - see 'HTML5 video Support' note at the link below. You also need to set a WebChromeClient for the WebView which is called when anything affecting the UI happens - see the note 'Full Screen Support' at the same link also:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

You can find a full working example which appears to be well maintained here:

- https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView

Your server then just has to serve the static video file in the same way it would any static content and it will be delivered using HTTP progressive downloading which looks and feels like streaming to your end user.

This does have limitations, however, as it is not 'real' streaming and you can't for example support adaptive bit rate streaming which allows you deliver different bit rates depending on the network connection. It much simpler however and it does not require a dedicated streaming server.

If you do want to use a dedicated streaming server then it is worth being aware that this is a relatively complex domain and that there are some open source streaming servers available that you might want to take a look at, for example:

- http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org
- http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html